# How do I use a range with MS Excel COUNTIF

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns of numbers - Columns A and B.  I'd like to get a total of the number of rows in which A > B.  The COUNTIF function seems right but I can't figure out how to use a range in the 2nd argument.  For example:

=COUNTIF(A1:A35, A1>B1.....A35>B35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `sumproduct` for this. Try `=SumProduct((A1:A35 > B1:B35)*1)`

Edited to add: `sumproduct` allows you to string together a bunch of tests on a range of cells, each of which will return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` or, in other words a `1` or `0`. These conditions get multiplied together as it tests each one, and the result for each row produces a `1` or a `0`. It does this for each row in your range (all ranges in the `sumproduct` must be the same length, and calculates the sum of the results.

The `sumproduct` above has just a single condition of `A1:A35>B1:B35`. The `*1` just tells `sumproduct` to give back the result as a number. If a row condition returns `TRUE` then you end up with `1*1`, otherwise you end up with `0*1`. Those results are added together for all 35 rows in the range to give you a total which is the number of rows where the condition is true.

It's confusing to learn, but it's crazy powerful for an excel function, and the ability to do multiple conditions makes it a powerhouse. For instance, if you only wanted to count where `A1:A35>B1:B35` when `B1:B35` is greater than `10` you could write `=sumproduct((A1:A35>B1:B35)*(B1:B35>10)*1)`

Answer (score 1):

COUNT rows based on criteria, ok.

With Excel you may use the "conditional sum wizard", or make your own similarly styled. 
I recommend the first :-)

On the other hand `=SUM(IF(A1:A35<B1:B35,1,0))` entered in a cell with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
Will do the job ;-) -- now you need to read up on "3D-formulas".

`COUNTIF()` does its job on a single cell at a time though. So doesn't provide the functionality you need.